# Vuejs2 - How to update the whole object from the server not losing reactivity?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a list of objects that can be updated from the database.

So, when I load the list, objects have only id and name.

When I click on an object I load other fields that can be of any length - that's why I don't load them with the objects in the list.

I found that when I update an object it can be difficult to keep reactivity https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html so I need to find some workaround.

this code works almost okay:

```
    axios.get('/api/news', item.id).then(function(response){
        if (response){
            Object.assign(item, response.data.item);
        }
    });
```

But the problem is the fields that have not been presented from the beginning is **not** 100% reactive anymore. What is going on is a new field has been updated reactively only when I change another, previous one. So, if I show 2 text field with old and new properties, if I change the second property, the field will not be updated until I change the first one.

I got item object from the component:

```
data () {
        return {
            items: [], 
        }
},
```

and

```
            <div v-for="item in items" @click="selectItem(item)" >
                <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            </div>
```

Then item's been passed to the function selectItem.

What is the proper pattern to load new fields *and* keep them reactive? (NB: it's not the case when I can assign field by field - I want to reuse the same code no matter which object it is, so I need so the solution for updating an object at a time without listing all new fields.)

Note. This code works inside the component.

Comment: So you want to add properties to a tracked object at runtime?  [Vue.set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Comment: @StevenB.That's correct. Another requirement I want to add them all together, not "field by field".

Answer (score 3):

Completely revised post: Ok, the example you give uses an array, which has [its own caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats), in particular that you can't directly set values like `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue` and have it react.

So you have to use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) with the array as the first argument and the index as the second. Here's an example that adds a `name` property to object items and then uses `Vue.set` to set the item to a new object created by `Object.assign`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
      id: 1,
      other: 'data'

    }, {
      id: 2,
      other: 'thingy'
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    selectItem(parent, key) {
      const newObj = Object.assign({}, parent[key], {
        name: 'some new name'
      });

      Vue.set(parent, key, newObj);
      setTimeout(() => {parent[key].name = 'Look, reactive!';}, 1500);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item, index in items" @click="selectItem(items, index)">
    <span>{{item.name || 'empty'}}</span>
  </div>
  <pre>
  {{JSON.stringify(items, null, 2)}}
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, actually I tried this code before. I tried it again. It's not working at all. I don't know why. If I do what I did - at least I saw reactive getters and setters from Vue - but in this case it just creates a simple object without any reactive getters and setters.

Comment: Where is `item` declared? If it's not reactive to begin with, it won't become reactive.

Comment: @mimic Have a look at my completely revised answer.

Comment: Roy J I tried your snippet, it works in the same way as mine - that is properties not 100% responsive (please see my explanation in the question) - a new field is updated only when I update the existing one - it's weird.

Comment: @mimic Apparently the assign-back-to-itself doesn't work properly. Example updated.

Comment: Roy J Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. It's the same case as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379044/vue-js-update-only-works-if-other-property-changed - so I should assign field-by-field, or create a separate object property for it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Change-Detection-Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) Vue cannot detect property addition or     deletion if you use "normal assign" methods.
You must use `Vue.set(object, key, value)`
Try something like the following:

```
axios.get('/api/news', item.id).then(function(response){
        if (response){
            let item = {}
            Vue.set(item, 'data', response.data.item)
        }
});
```

Than `item.data` would than be reactiv.

Comment: Yeah, I used this approach in the past and thought I would be able to find another approach without creating additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

Can simply use Vue.set to update this.item reactively

```
axios.get('/api/news', item.id).then(function(response){
    if (response){
        this.$set(this, "item", response.data.item);
    }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).